# QUERY error NO_COLUMN:col1

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

```
=query(importrange("12HAbnTv4g_6m1UeCOs9ZO0gAYvy8tlaXr-cc2ecPEic","Master!A:ba"),
 "select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col53 
  where col53<> 'Deal Cancelled'",0)
```

is resulting in error message:

> Unable to parse query string for Function Query parameter 2:NO_COLUMN:col1

Answer (score 1):

**`col1,col2,col3...`** needs to be: **`Col1,Col2,Col3...`**

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("12HAbnTv4g_6m1UeCOs9ZO0gAYvy8tlaXr-cc2ecPEic", "Master!A:BA"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col53 
  where Col53 <> 'Deal Cancelled'", 0)
```